# Ansible: iterate over a list of dictionaries - loop vs. with_items

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm getting different results when using loop vs with_items when trying to iterate over a list of dictionaries.

I've tried using loop|dict2items (the structure isn't a dictionary, & it tells me as much. heh) and loop with the flatten filter.

Here is the list of dictionaries:

```
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "id1", 
            "ip": "ip1", 
            "name": "name1"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "id2", 
            "ip": "ip2", 
            "name": "name2"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "id3", 
            "ip": "ip3", 
            "name": "name3"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "id4", 
            "ip": "ip4", 
            "name": "name4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the task in the playbook:

```
 - name: Add privateIp windows_instances to inventory
        add_host:
          name: "{{ item.ip }}"
          aws_name: "{{ item.name }}"
          groups: windows_instances
          aws_instanceid: "{{ item.id }}"
          ansible_user: "{{ windows_user }}"
          ansible_password: "{{ windows_password }}"
          ansible_port: 5985
          ansible_connection: winrm
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
        loop:
          - "{{ list1 | flatten(levels=1) }}"
```

When attempting to run the above code, I get the "list object has no attribute" error. I've tried different flatten levels to no avail.

*HOWEVER...*

If I simply replace the loop above with:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ list1 }}"
```

Everything works perfectly. I'm missing something in the with_items > loop translation here...

Answer (score 18):

Don't put a `-` before your list.

And here, you have a list of dicts, so you don't need to flatten neither.

This playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    demo_list:
      - ip: 1.2.3.4
        id: 1
        name: demo1
      - ip: 2.2.3.4
        id: 2
        name: demo2
      - ip: 3.2.3.4
        id: 3
        name: demo3

  tasks:

    - name: the list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ demo_list }}"

    - name: unflattened list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.id }} {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}"
      loop:
        "{{ demo_list }}"

    - name: flattened list == unflattened list in this case
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.id }} {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}"
      loop:
        "{{ demo_list | flatten(levels=1) }}"
```

gives this result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************

TASK [the list] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "ip": "1.2.3.4", 
            "name": "demo1"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "ip": "2.2.3.4", 
            "name": "demo2"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "ip": "3.2.3.4", 
            "name": "demo3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [unflattened list] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "1 1.2.3.4 demo1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "2 2.2.3.4 demo2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "3 3.2.3.4 demo3"
}

TASK [flattened list == unflattened list in this case] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "1 1.2.3.4 demo1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "2 2.2.3.4 demo2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "3 3.2.3.4 demo3"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Oh weird! I had no idea... I thought that the - was the correct notation for items to loop through! Can you explain the difference/significance?

Comment: That actually didn't work. Produced the following error:
```ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The offending line appears to be:

          "{{ list1 }}"
          "{{ list2 }}"
          ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: What didn't work ? I don't have `list2` in my example... You probably write something like `"{{ list1 }}" "{{ list2 }}"`instead of `"{{ list1 }} {{ list2 }}"`

Comment: Hmm... writing "{{ list1 }} {{ list2 }}" gave the following error: "FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead:"