# In Ansible, replace the use of `with_items` by `loop` with a list of dictionaries defined in-line

Tags: loops, ansible

In old-style Ansible, I used to use `with_items` together with dictionaries. To given potential examples:

```
- name: deploy files
  template:
    src: "files/{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
  with_items:
    - {src: 'foo', dest: "/path/to/somewhere"}
    - {src: 'bar', dest: "/somewhere/else"}
    - {src: 'baz', dest: "/different/path/"}


- name: Install packages
  npm:
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    version: '{{ item.version }}'
  with_items:
    - {src: 'foo', version: '1.0'}
    - {src: 'bar', version: '1.5'}
    - {src: 'baz', version: '1.2'}
```

These days we are supposed to use `loop`. if trying as a drop-in replacement, this would be like

```
- name: deploy files
  template:
    src: "files/{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
  loop:
    - {src: 'foo', dest: "/path/to/somewhere"}
    - {src: 'bar', dest: "/somewhere/else"}
    - {src: 'baz', dest: "/different/path/"}
```

wihch fails with

```
TASK [deploy files] ************
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'src_path' is undefined"
}
```

Indeed, the [migration guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items) (and StackOverflow answers such as [Ansible: iterate over a list of dictionaries - loop vs. with_items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425311)) do say and boil down to “use `flatten`” for dictionaries. But this assumes that the list of dicts is stored in a variable. But what if it is not as it is defined in-line? Do I just have to move the data to a named variable?

EDIT: for an attempt with drop-in replacement.

Comment: Just for your consideration: no one has suggested removing `with_items` from ansible that I know of; it's not going anywhere so you are only making your life worse by trying to shoe-horn something into `loop:` that isn't working for you

Comment: For some reason I thought I had read that `with_*` was already planned for deprecation ; but indeed that does not appear to be the case. Also, I was under the impression that loop should Just Work™ and that I must be missing something basic ; but I certainly don’t mind using `with_items`. :-)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working as expected with your first example task ? I don't see anything wrong with it. Using raw `loo` is equivalent to `with_list` which would have the exact same effect as `with_items` in this particular case.

Comment: Good point @Zeitounator − clarified the example tasks, and the example try with a drop-in replacement and the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, `loop` *is* a drop-in replacement for `with_items` when using in-line-defined list of dictionaries.

(I had an undefined variable somewhere else which just ''happened'' to be named in a way (`src_path`) that confused me with the `src` dict variables… >_>)